# How to get all values from two edittexts with textview as recyclerview item and set in another sectioned recyclerview in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am new in Android and am stuck on an issue from quite long. So I have a tab activity with 3 tabs named `B`, `L` and `W`. All of them have same `RecyclerView` with one `TextView` and 2 `EditText`s. The `EditText`s accept numbers. After I enter value in last `EditText`, I get a checkout button. When I click on it, I want to get all `EditText` entered values across all 3 fragments with their respective `TextView`s on another `RecyclerView` on an alert dialog in a sectioned manner such that below `B` header, I get `EditText` values with it's `TextView`s from `B` fragment, similarly for `L` and `W`. Here's what I've tried:

Main Adapter code:

```
public class NewOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<NewOrderModel> newOrderList; //Main Arraylist
private ArrayList<CheckoutDialogModel> checkoutList; //Arraylist to be made
Context mContext;
String itemCode, casesEtVal, bottlesEtVal;
String[] arrCases, arrBottles; //Array for getting edittext values
ArrayList<String> skuArray = new ArrayList<>(); //textview array
ArrayList<String> casesArray = new ArrayList<>(); //Edittext1 array
ArrayList<String> bottlesArray = new ArrayList<>(); //Edittext2 array

boolean isOnTextChanged = false;
int id;

public NewOrderAdapter(ArrayList<NewOrderModel> newOrderList, Context context) {
    this.newOrderList = newOrderList;
    this.mContext = context;
    arrCases = new String[newOrderList.size()];
    arrBottles = new String[newOrderList.size()];
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.new_order_recycler_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NewOrderModel model = newOrderList.get(position);
    holder.txtModelName.setText(model.getItemCode());
    id = model.getId();
    holder.edtPrice1.setTag(position);
    holder.edtPrice1.setText(newOrderList.get(position).getCasesPrice());
    holder.edtPrice2.setTag(position);
    holder.edtPrice2.setText(newOrderList.get(position).getUnitsPrice());
    holder.edtPrice2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(v, "",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.new_order_snack, null);
        snackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Snackbar.SnackbarLayout snackbarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout)snackbar.getView();
        snackbarLayout.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
        Button btnCheckout = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCheckOut); //Checkout button
        btnCheckout.setOnClickListener(v12 -> {
            ArrayList<String> fSKUarray = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> fCasesArray = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> fBottlesArray = new ArrayList<>();
            if (!casesArray.isEmpty() && !bottlesArray.isEmpty()) {
                for (int i = 0; i< casesArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (!casesArray.get(i).equals("0") && !casesArray.get(i).equals("")){
                        fCasesArray.add(casesArray.get(i));
                        fSKUarray.add(skuArray.get(i));
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i<bottlesArray.size(); i++) {
                    if (!bottlesArray.get(i).equals("0") && !bottlesArray.get(i).equals("")) {
                        fBottlesArray.add(bottlesArray.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.checkout_dialog, null);
            RecyclerView orderRecycler = view1.findViewById(R.id.orderRecycler);
            orderRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
            orderRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view1.getContext()));
            orderRecycler.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(view1.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
            checkoutList = new ArrayList<CheckoutDialogModel>(){
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < newOrderList.size(); i++){
                        if (casesEtVal != null && bottlesEtVal != null){
                            String sku = newOrderList.get(i).getItemCode();
                            switch (newOrderList.get(i).getGroupCode()) {
                                case "114":
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("BEER", "", "", ""));
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("", "", sku,
                                            newOrderList.get(i).getCasesPrice() + "."+ newOrderList.get(i).getUnitsPrice()));
                                    break;
                                case "115":
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("LIQUOR", "", "", ""));
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("", "", sku,
                                            newOrderList.get(i).getCasesPrice() + "."+ newOrderList.get(i).getUnitsPrice()));
                                    break;
                                case "109":
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("WINE", "", "", ""));
                                    add(new CheckoutDialogModel("", "", sku,
                                            newOrderList.get(i).getCasesPrice() + "."+ newOrderList.get(i).getUnitsPrice()));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            checkoutList = getCheckoutList();
            CheckoutDialogAdapter mAdapter = new CheckoutDialogAdapter();
            mAdapter.setCheckOutList(checkoutList);
            orderRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            snackbar.dismiss();
            builder.setView(view1);
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            Button btnPlaceOrdr = view1.findViewById(R.id.btnPlaceOrdr);
            btnPlaceOrdr.setOnClickListener(v13 -> {
                dialog.dismiss();
            });
            dialog.show();
        });
        snackbarLayout.addView(view, 0);
        snackbar.show();
    });
}
public ArrayList<CheckoutDialogModel> getCheckoutList() {
    return checkoutList;
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return newOrderList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtModelName;
    private EditText edtPrice1, edtPrice2;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtModelName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.modelName);
        edtPrice1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price1);
        edtPrice2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price2);
        edtPrice1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (edtPrice1.getTag()!= null) {
                    newOrderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setCasesPrice(edtPrice1.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (isOnTextChanged) {
                    isOnTextChanged = false;
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i<= id; i++) {
                            if (i!=id){
                                skuArray.add("0");
                                casesArray.add("0");
                            } else {
                                skuArray.add("0");
                                casesArray.add("0");
                                skuArray.set(id, newOrderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getItemCode());
                                casesArray.set(id, casesEtVal);
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("skuList", skuArray.toString());
                        Log.d("casesList", casesArray.toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        for (int i = 0; i<= id; i++) {
                            if (i == id) {
                                skuArray.set(id,"0");
                                casesArray.set(id,"0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        edtPrice2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                isOnTextChanged = true;
                if (edtPrice2.getTag()!=null) {
                    newOrderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setUnitsPrice(edtPrice2.getText().toString());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (isOnTextChanged) {
                    isOnTextChanged = false;
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i<= id; i++) {
                            if (i!=id){
                                skuArray.add("0");
                                casesArray.add("0");
                                bottlesArray.add("0");
                            } else {
                                skuArray.add("0");
                                casesArray.add("0");
                                bottlesArray.add("0");
                                skuArray.set(id, newOrderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getItemCode());
                                casesArray.set(id, casesEtVal);
                                bottlesArray.set(id, bottlesEtVal);
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("skuList", skuArray.toString());
                        Log.d("casesList", casesArray.toString());
                        Log.d("bottlesList", bottlesArray.toString());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
                        for (int i = 0; i<= id; i++) {
                            if (i == id) {
                                skuArray.set(id,"0");
                                casesArray.set(id,"0");
                                bottlesArray.set(id,"0");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                casesEtVal = edtPrice1.getText().toString();
                arrCases[getAdapterPosition()] = casesEtVal;
                bottlesEtVal = edtPrice2.getText().toString();
                arrBottles[getAdapterPosition()] = bottlesEtVal;
                if (!casesEtVal.equals("") && !bottlesEtVal.equals("")) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(bottlesEtVal) > Integer.parseInt(casesEtVal)) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Bottles can't be more than Cases!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        edtPrice2.setText(newOrderList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getUnitsPrice().replace(bottlesEtVal, ""));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

CheckoutDialogAdapter.java

```
public class CheckoutDialogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<CheckoutDialogModel> mArrayList;
private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 2;

public CheckoutDialogAdapter() {}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER){
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checkout_dialog_header, parent, false);
        return new VHHeader(v);
    }
        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checkout_dialog_item, parent, false);
        return new VHItem(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        VHItem vhItem = ((VHItem)holder);
        vhItem.itemName.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getItemName());
        vhItem.itemQty.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getItemQty());
    } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
        VHHeader vhHeader = ((VHHeader)holder);
        vhHeader.headerName.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getHeaderName());
        vhHeader.headerQty.setText(mArrayList.get(position).getHeaderQty());
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mArrayList == null ? 0 : mArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mArrayList.get(position).itemName)) {
        return TYPE_HEADER;
    } else {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
}

public void setCheckOutList(ArrayList<CheckoutDialogModel> arrayList) {
    this.mArrayList = arrayList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView headerName, headerQty;
    LinearLayout headerLayout;

    public VHHeader(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        headerName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerName);
        headerQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerQty);
        headerLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
    }
}

public class VHItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView itemName, itemQty;
    LinearLayout itemLayout;

    public VHItem(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
        itemQty = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemQty);
        itemLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemLayout);
    }
}
```

}

Right now I am facing an issue that the checkout list is taking the complete array's values and not what I am entering. Even the checkout list is not coming in sectioned manner.